# ASP.NET Start Download after Page Load

Tags: asp.net, redirect, onload

I have this code to start a download after the page was displayed to the user:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://myserver.com/myfile.zip", false);   
    }
```

But the redirect is done before the page loads and the page never loads.

How can I start the download and finish displaying the page to the client?

I cannot use Transmit.File, because the file is located on a different server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "java", "setTimeout(Redirect, 9000);", true);
}
```

In aspx page make a javascript function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect() {
        window.location = 'http://myserver.com/myfile.zip';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the page is not displayed, I have added even 15 seconds delay, and after the delay the download starts without displaying the page.

Comment: Try above code,...9000 is the delay in milliseconds after which redirection occurs

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to popup a dialog to download a CSV file.  Perhaps something like this could work for you?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=export.csv");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); // In my case, the StringBuilder object was the file to be written.  I don't know exactly what you'd for a non dynamic file.
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: I can't use write or transmit file, because the file is on another server.